# Not able to fire click event programatically(through javascript) in IE browser(in Chrome it works fine)

Tags: javascript

I have used following things also:

```
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
event.initMouseEvent("click",true,true,window,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);
button.dispatchEvent(btnEvent);
```

In short i want to fire `click` event through javascript(dont want to use handler,just click event only).
Please help me out of this issue, thnx in advance.

Comment: `initMouseEvent()` has been deprecated and MDN doesn't show any IE implementation for it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent

Comment: @Tejas1991 can't you use jquery ?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using JQuery, you may be able to use `trigger`. See docs here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_trigger.asp.

Otherwise, here's a native JavaScript implementation: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#trigger_custom

Answer (score -1):

this can be achieved with jquery [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) with less pain

```
$(button).trigger('click')
```